# When is it appropriate to use the residuals from one model as data for another?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, residuals

I came across the opinion to never use the residuals from one model as data for another model in both the lecture ([linked time stamp for his comments](https://youtu.be/e0tO64mtYMU?t=1975)) and text (excerpt below, maintaining the original emphasis and cited reference) by Richard McElreath [1]. But I see this technique used in machine learning [2,3], and I have some sense using the residuals is some form of feature extraction.

> **Rethinking: Residuals are parameters, not data.** There is a tradition, especially in parts of biology, of using residuals from one model as data in another model. For example, a biologist might regress brain size on body size and then use the brain size residuals as data in another model. This procedure is always a mistake. Residuals are not known. They are parameters, variables with unobserved values. Treating them as known values throws away uncertainty. The right way to adjust for body size is to include it in the same model,[83] preferably a model designed in light of an explicit causal model.

Is using the residuals as demonstrated in Zhang et al. [2] inherently wrong or misguided? Can it be appropriate to use the residuals to only increase the predictive performance or feature engineering?

Disclosure: I asked a [similar question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/90168/is-it-wrong-to-use-residuals-from-one-model-as-data-in-another-model) on the Data science SE, but I tried to change the question in regards to the [answer of cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243797/952049).

**References**

[1] McElreath, R. (2020). Statistical rethinking: A Bayesian course with examples in R and Stan. CRC press. Page 137.

[2] Zhang, H., Nettleton, D., & Zhu, Z. (2019). Regression-enhanced random forests. arXiv preprint arXiv:1904.10416. [Link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.10416.pdf)

[3] Modelling currently infected cases of covid-19 using h2o driverless ai. (2020, March 30). Retrieved March 02, 2021, from https://www.h2o.ai/blog/modelling-currently-infected-cases-of-covid-19-using-h2o-driverless-ai/

[83] Freckleton, R. P. (2002). On the misuse of residuals in ecology: regression of residuals vs. multiple regression. Journal of Animal Ecology, 71:542–545. [Link](https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1046/j.1365-2656.2002.00618.x)

Comment: It can be both wrong or right. McElreath's point that naive uncertainty quantification is difficult when you fit (estimated) residuals as if they were known is fair. However, there are methods for non naive uncertainty quantification. Fitting of residuals could roughly be viewed as a greedy approximation to a joint optimization problem. Greedy algorithms are certainly sometimes problematic given their restrictions.

Comment: On the other hand, some well known and standard statistical methods such as gradient boosting are based on iteratively fitting residuals in a greedy approach--and variance estimates available in some gradient boosting settings!

Comment: Can you explain the difference between naive uncertainty quantification and non naive uncertainty quantification? McElreath never distinguishes between the two, and I am not familiar with the distinction

Comment: A naive way to quantify uncertainty with residuals is to assume that the residuals are outcomes--this pretends like the first step of finding the residuals never happened. This is bad. A non naive way is to take into account the process of finding the residuals. This can be done in many ways. For example, in the following paper, they (1) fit a random forest then (2) fit a random forest to the residuals and they manage to find the distribution of the prediction using the jackknife. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.12561.pdf

Comment: I think I am understanding the difference between naive and non naive uncertainty.

With Naive uncertainty we ignores the error or uncertainty within the residuals, correct me if I am wrong. The last jump is where I am finding some difficulty understanding. How do you account for the process for finding the residuals since the residuals are just the difference between the true values and the fitted values. What are we doing when we “account for the process for finding the residuals”?