Why estimates of data via residuals has 50/50 effect on significance compared to original data?
I am generating data according to the following model

In the real dataset, variable I is unknown and the goal is to study the relationship between I and D, B11, to see if it is significantly non-zero.  To this end, in simulated data where I is known, a method using the I values is compared to a method using their estimates via residuals of G ~ B. In other words I ~ D is compared to (residuals of [G ~ B]) ~ D.  According to my R code below, on the median the two significance tests are the same and on the average, directly using I is ever slightly better.
What is the explanation for this and why is not the "obvious" idea that because the residuals are simply an estimate of variable I rather than the real thing that it always gives more unreliable results?  Instead only giving worse results half the time? And better the other half?
# Part A:
set.seed(0); n <- 40; numSims <- 10000; ronDsigs <- c(); 
IonDsigs <- c()
B8s <- B9s <- B10s <- B11s <- B12s <- c()
for (index1 in 1:numSims) {
    B <- rnorm(n); I <- rnorm(n); J <- rnorm(n)
    B8 <- rnorm(1); B9 <- rnorm(1); B10 <- rnorm(1); B11 <- rnorm(1); 
    B12 <- rnorm(1)
    B8s <- c(B8s, B8); B9s <- c(B9s, B9); B10s <- c(B10s, B10); 
    B11s <- c(B11s, B11);
    B12s <- c(B12s, B12)
    G <- B*B8 + I*B10; D <- B*B9 + I*B11 + J*B12
    GonB <- lm(G ~ B)
    GonBresiduals <- GonB$residuals
GonBresidualsonD <- lm(GonBresiduals ~ D)
IonD <- lm(I ~ D)
ronDsigs <- c(ronDsigs, 
              summary(GonBresidualsonD)$coefficients[[8]])
    IonDsigs <- c(IonDsigs, summary(IonD)$coefficients[[8]])
}
rminI <- ronDsigs - IonDsigs
summary(rminI)

# Part B: Identical Repeat of Part A except B8,B9,B10,B11,B12
#   all have constant values this time.
set.seed(0); n <- 40; numSims <- 10000; ronDsigs <- c(); 
IonDsigs <- c()
B8s <- B9s <- B10s <- B11s <- B12s <- c()
for (index1 in 1:numSims) {
    B <- rnorm(n); I <- rnorm(n); J <- rnorm(n)
    B8 <- 3; B9 <- 1; B10 <- 2; B11 <- 11; B12 <- 19
    B8s <- c(B8s, B8); B9s <- c(B9s, B9); B10s <- c(B10s, B10); 
    B11s <- c(B11s, B11);
    B12s <- c(B12s, B12)
    G <- B*B8 + I*B10; D <- B*B9 + I*B11 + J*B12
    GonB <- lm(G ~ B)
    GonBresiduals <- GonB$residuals
GonBresidualsonD <- lm(GonBresiduals ~ D)
IonD <- lm(I ~ D)
ronDsigs <- c(ronDsigs, 
              summary(GonBresidualsonD)$coefficients[[8]])
    IonDsigs <- c(IonDsigs, summary(IonD)$coefficients[[8]])
}
rminI <- ronDsigs - IonDsigs
summary(rminI)


I'll focus on the second model with fixed coefficients. In that case, it's because the estimate of I based on the residuals of lm(G~B) is very, very good (particularly when compared against the large uncertainty due to the coefficient of 12 for the error due to J in constructing D). Your construction of G is:
G <- B*B8+I*B10

with no additional error term. Residuals from that model necessarily track, almost exactly, with I.
To see what happens when that estimate of I isn't so good, try including an additional error term in that construction of G. For example, in setting up the values for the n=40 observations in each simulation, add an error term:
B<-rnorm(n); I<-rnorm(n); J<-rnorm(n); err <-rnorm(n)

then include that in your construction of G:
G <- B*B8 +I*B10 + 10*err

That will give you what you expect (in terms of the p-values you used for comparisons, although that might not the best way to evaluate different models).
summary(rminI)
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
# -0.8021  0.1627  0.4052  0.4314  0.6941  0.9998 

Before you go further down this path in trying to estimate the unknown I from the observables, I very strongly recommend that you consult with an experienced statistician. Your model involves a lot of assumptions about strict linearity and a lack of interactions, assumptions that probably don't hold in practice and are likely to lead you astray.

Thanks EdM, I appreciate all the work you're doing answering my second question in a row now, but is it possible a more theoretical answer exists?  Originally I was going to post this model as as counterexample your answer here https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/652623/398015 since it shows multiple regression of G ~ B + D does not work, whereas regression using residuals does work.  But I decided not to post it there yet because I wanted to keep working through it more first.  I also found this post with no answer that asks the same question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/512333/398015

So my question is still about when using residuals as data is okay. and then second for this question, is there some theory about why the estimated errors given by the residuals sometimes improves the correlation with D?  I can understand if because the residuals are only an estimate of I, that they always correlate less significantly with D than I itself does, but this only happens half the time.  Exactly half of the other time it actually becomes more strongly correlated.  What's going on there?

@AFriendlyFish using residuals as data isn't OK in ordinary least squares regression unless the predictors are completely uncorrelated. Otherwise you are essentially engaged in forward stepwise regression, with its risks of overfitting while missing important predictors. It can be OK if it's part of a penalization or randomization process to avoid those problems, as in random forests or boosted trees. See this page and its links, for example.

@AFriendlyFish residuals seem to work better in half your comparisons because, in your example, there is almost no difference between the lm(G~B) residuals and the I values. With the very high error term in D (J*B12) your two models are almost identical. The p-values are dominated by that error term. With no practical difference in the two models, you are just seeing the variation in p-values due to random sampling around two almost identical models, with one being "better" half the time by chance. If you add a large enough error to G, as I do, that equivalence goes away.

@AFriendlyFish see this page for how one can use properly constructed residuals in both outcome and predictor variables to reproduce standard multiple regression. There's no practical advantage to that approach, however.
